# Rider IDE Docker Compose debugging not working

Tags: c#, docker, debugging, docker-compose, rider

I develop an ASP.NET multiservice app with Rider IDE.

Each individual service runs in a separate Docker container. Everything runs together through Docker Compose.

When I set breakpoints and start debugging via the "Debug" button, the application does not stop at the breakpoints.

The debug tab does not even become active. I tried running debugging in Visual Studio. It worked as it should.

- Rider 2023.1.1
- Docker Desktop 4.19.0
- Option Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS Enabled
- Option Use Docker Compose V2 Enabled

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API"
RUN dotnet build "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.API.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  catalog.db:
    image: mongo
  
  catalog.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}catalog.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Dockerfile

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  catalog.db: 
    container_name: catalog.db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
  
  catalog.api:
    container_name: catalog.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalog.db:27017"
    depends_on:
      - catalog.db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
```

[image: Run/Debug Configuration window in Rider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed in Rider version 2023.1.2.

Comment: Are you sure about It? Still having problems while docker compose debugging